# Read .bin file in Nuget Package from C#

Tags: c#, nuget, binaryfiles

I created my own C# Class Library nuget package for UWP.
Currently, it works all good. When it runs, it uses .bin file in Assets folder.

**My question is this:

I want to include this .bin file in my nuget package also. And want to read it from UWP class library (in buffer).**

I did below approach
In .nuspec add my .bin to content
<file src="..\myPath\model.bin" target="content\myPath"/> 
this makes my nuget package contain model.bin file under content

But I don't know how to read this file. It is not contained in \bin. 
It exists only in .nuget\packages\myNuget\content 
**How can I read it?**

Thank you for your time.
Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: does this help [NuGet ContentFiles Demystified](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/)